# Dropdown field listing all roles

Tags: users

Is there a way to populate a content type field with the custom roles registered in Drupal (minus authenticated and anonymous)???

I have googled and found only quick hacks using custom modules, etc. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your looking for a module then there is [Role Field](https://drupal.org/project/role_field) that creates a new field type that allows you to choose from the list of roles.